# How to clear cache for just 1 website on WebView Android?

Tags: android, webview

I know how to clear the Android WebView cache for whole app (`webview.clearCache(true)`);

But I have multiple websites that load on the same WebView.

How do I clear cache for just 1 website?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but it's a good question.